# Multiplication of blockmatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, block-matrices

For my university studies I was given this statement to prove:

$\begin {pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix} W & X \\ Y & Z\end {pmatrix}  = \begin {pmatrix} AW + BY & AX +BZ \\ CW + DY & CX + DZ\end {pmatrix}\ $

Where:

$A,W \in R^{n \times n}, \,\, D,Z \in R^{m \times m} \,\, B,X \in R^{n \times m} \,\, and \,\, C,Y \in R^{m \times n}$

My problem ist that I have no clue how to even start my proof. Since I'm very confused by that many elements from different matices inside these blockmatrices.

Comment: Where does $D$ fit into the original block matrices?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Definitions are your friends.  Pick an element of the product matrix and apply the definition of matrix multiplication to determine an expression for it.  Then compare what you get to the result you are expected to prove.

Comment: @Arthur The first matrix should probably be $\begin {pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end {pmatrix}$

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. It should be there instead of the C and the C instead of the second B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition as follows:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|cc}
  a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}&b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1m}\\
  \vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
  a_{n1}&\cdots&a_{nn}&b_{n1}&\cdots&b_{nm}\\
  c_{11}&\cdots&c_{1n}&d_{11}&\cdots&d_{1m}\\
  \vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
  c_{m1}&\cdots&c_{mn}&d_{m1}&\cdots&d_{mm}\\
\end{array}
\right]\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
  w_{11}&\cdots&w_{1n}&x_{11}&\cdots&x_{1m}\\
  \vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
  w_{n1}&\cdots&w_{nn}&x_{n1}&\cdots&x_{nm}\\
\hline
  y_{11}&\cdots&y_{1n}&z_{11}&\cdots&z_{1m}\\
  \vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
  y_{m1}&\cdots&y_{mn}&z_{m1}&\cdots&z_{mm}\\
\end{array}
\right]= \\
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
  \vdots&&\vdots\\
  a_{n1}&\cdots&a_{nn}\\
\hline
  c_{11}&\cdots&c_{1n}\\
  \vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
  c_{m1}&\cdots&c_{mn}\\
\end{array}
\right]\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|cc}
  w_{11}&\cdots&w_{1n}&x_{11}&\cdots&x_{1m}\\
  \vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
  w_{n1}&\cdots&w_{nn}&x_{n1}&\cdots&x_{nm}\\
\end{array}
\right]+\\
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1n}\\
  \vdots&&\vdots\\
  b_{n1}&\cdots&b_{nn}\\
\hline
  d_{11}&\cdots&d_{1n}\\
  \vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
  d_{m1}&\cdots&d_{mn}\\
\end{array}
\right]\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|cc}
  y_{11}&\cdots&y_{1n}&z_{11}&\cdots&z_{1m}\\
  \vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
  y_{n1}&\cdots&y_{nn}&z_{n1}&\cdots&z_{nm}\\
\end{array}
\right]= \\
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  AW&AX\\
\hline
  CW&CX\\
\end{array}
\right]+
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  BY&BZ\\
\hline
  DY&DZ\\
\end{array}
\right]=\\
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  AW+BY&AX+BZ\\
\hline
  CW+DY&CX+DZ\\
\end{array}
\right]=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  AW+BY&AX+BZ\\
  CW+DY&CX+DZ\\
\end{array}
\right].$$

Refer to this [source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlockMatrix.html):

> When two block matrices have the same shape and their diagonal blocks are square matrices, then they multiply similarly to matrix multiplication.

Comment: I find this maze of dots more confusing than anything else

Answer (score 3):

Just refer to the definition for [**matrix product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), that is if $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix and $B$ is an $m\times p$ matrix, then $C=A\cdot B$ is an $n\times p$ matrix with

$$c_{ij} = a_{i1}b_{1j} +\cdots + a_{im}b_{mj}= \sum_{k=1}^m a_{ik}b_{kj}$$

and by linearity

$$\begin {pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix} W & X \\ Y & Z\end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix} W & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end {pmatrix} + \begin {pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix} 0 & X \\ 0 & 0\end {pmatrix}+$$$$+\begin {pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ Y & 0\end {pmatrix}+\begin {pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & Z\end {pmatrix} $$

Comment: Yes that was what I was thinking about too but I have absolutly no clue how to transfer this to blockmatrices

Comment: @Mathmeeeeen The first entry in the first row is the dot product of the first row of the first matrix times the first column of the second matrix, the second entry in the first row is the dot product of the first row of the first matrix times the second column of the second matrix, and so on. It is a little long but we can show in that way that the identity holds.

Comment: But then the first entry in the first row would be (a11...a1n b1 ... b1m) (w11 ... wn1 y11 ... ym1) and i don't know how to write that in short. And when I did this for all the entries how I can conclude from that, that the first entry in the first row would be AW + BY

Comment: @Mathmeeeeen You can use linearity to simplify the derivation.

Comment: @Mathmeeeeen Can you prove that $$\begin {pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix} W & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end {pmatrix}  = \begin {pmatrix} AW & 0 \\ CW  & 0\end {pmatrix}\ $$